# Plot Condensed Dataset

Tags: matlab, plot

So I have a sample dataset which I need to plot using Matlab.
The columns look like this:

[image: Plot Table Data]

Obviously due to this data set the plot looks exceptionally condensed.

[image]

Now I am totally new to plotting and statistical data processing.

**What can be done to make the data plot more visually comparable/perusal-able (plotting at larger intervals?)?**

Here's the code I wrote:

```
fid=fopen('me.dat', 'r');
s=textscan(fid,'%s %s %f %f', 'headerlines', 1);
fclose(fid);
a=s{1};
b=s{2};
c=s{3};
d=s{4};
plot(c,d)
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you upload your sample data file so that we can try a few things out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I have this kind of problem, I usually use the following methods:

1) Plot only every certain point. If you have 1D arrays `a` and `b` and you want to plot, say, every 5th point, use `plot(a(1:5:end),b(1:5:end))`, instead of `plot(a,b)`. This works, because `a(1:5:end)` returns `a(1), a(6), a(11), ...`, so that you will plot roughly 1/5 of your data points. Here you simply omit most of your data points, so I prefer the second method.

2) If you have Image Processing toolbox, use [imresize](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html?refresh=true). Before plotting, resize your data `aplot=imresize(a,0.2);` If you want to decrease the size of your array by a factor of N, the second argument of the `imresize` should be `1/N`. This generally works better, since you have an idea what's going on in your full dataset.